# Disable a button on a timer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am making a timer app on XCode 7 using Objective-C and I would like to disable the button that is connected to the action `startCount` while the following code is being executed

```
- (IBAction)startCount:(id)sender {

countInt = 0;
self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

What line of code would I need to add to this to disable the button connected to the action `startCount`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `disable` the sender via the [`enabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) flag:

```
((UIButton*)sender).enabled = false;
```

Don't forget to re-enable the button after the timer finishes.

> If the enabled state is NO, the control ignores touch events [...]

Alternatively to the cast I made in the above code: Change your method signature to take in a `UIButton*`, not just an id, that way you can make sure the cast will not fail. A slight variation of the cast would be to cast to `UIControl*` instead.

Comment: Ah; I think I misunderstood – I thought OP wanted the timer to disable the button, not to have the button disabled immediately.

Comment: @TwoStraws hmm, I did not think of *your* way of understanding the problem - lets just see what OP actually wants ;)

Comment: @luk2302 I added the line you suggested but it shows the error message Property 'enabled' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: @luk2302: I think it was the title that confused me "disable a button on a timer". Once they pick the answer that works like they expect, I may edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @peterbonar: Try changing `(id)sender` to be `(UIButton*)sender`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: to make your code easier to understand (and to avoid unpleasant race conditions if there are multiple buttons that might be tapped/disabled), I would suggest avoiding using a timer. Instead, consider `dispatch_after()` like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = false;
});
```

We get `sender` being passed into the method, and it will be the button that was tapped. `1 * NSEC_PER_SEC` means "delay for one second."